# Data base saving & Redirection issue using django

Tags: django, django-models

I have an issue, I do not know why it is happening and how to solve it; 
My app ask a user to create a project and is redirect directly to the project detail page. On that detail page if a team_id is empty I ask the user to create a team and when the team is created the user is redirected again to the project detail page to now be able to populate his team.

I used the code {% if Project.team_id == None %} when the user is redirected after creating his team but it is not working .. could you please help ? It is like before the redirection the new team is not saved in the Db .. 
my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Welcome to your Project {{  project.name }} Detail page</h2>
  </div>

  {% if Project.team_id == None %}
  <div class="invite-team">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="jumbo-text">
        <h3>It is time to link a team to your project  now create a new team and add team members</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="jumbo-button">
          <a href="{% url 'website:add_team' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>   Create a new team</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="invite-teammembers">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="jumbo-text">
          <h3>The team {{ project.team_id }} has beed created, we now need to add TeamMembers</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="jumbo-button">
            <a href="{% url 'registration:team_register' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>   Create a new team</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Yes it worked ;) what do you mean "Looking at your surrounding code, you are using project as the container of your project". my model Project is with a capital letter why now it is without ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your surrounding code, you are using `project` as the container of your project. However, in your statement you are using `Project` (first character uppercase). Changing `Project` to `project` might help.

Your comment question:

> what do you mean "Looking at your surrounding code, you are using project as the container of your project". my model Project is with a capital letter why now it is without ?

With `looking at the surrounding code` I mean that I literally looked at your code how you are using the variables in the other parts of your code. I am not sure if you are using [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/) (class based views) or [FBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/) (function based views).

With CBV the object is added to the context with the name defined in:
[DetailView:81](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L81) 
or  [ListView:104](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L104)

You can [override the context object name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts) by using the `context_object_name` in the View class

If you are using FBV, you have added it to the context manually as something like:

```
return render(request, 'myapp/template.html', {
    'project': <project_query_or_variable>,
})
```